# Support for "Personal Access Tokens" or "API keys"

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

Does keycloak provide a way to support Personal Access Tokens, similar to Github, when I am using Keycloak to handle authentication and using the tokens it issues to secure my API? When my application is using a web browser then logging in via OIDC flow works fine, but how can I handle login from a CLI or a headless API script for my application?

I could support a password flow where I get back a JWT token after providing a username and password, but I assume once the user has configured 2FA or if they are using SAML on the backend then all bets are off as a username and password would not get you access. This is exactly why Github offers personal access tokens. Is there some way to implement something like this using Keycloak or do we have to build it in our own application and then accept those tokens in addition to the JWT.

What I would envision is Keycloak being able to generate and store personal access tokens in its user store that a user could generate and revoke via the UI that Keycloak provides to the user. My CLI could then use this token to obtain a JWT and then proceed with calling my API the same way a web browser or other client would.

Comment: Hi, we are facing a similar issue. Have you solved the issue for your use case?

Comment: I left that position and no longer work with Keycloak, but we had not solved the problem at the time I left.

Comment: Kind of, we implemented it by our own using Spring Security with a separate Filter to validated if API Key is valid. We store the API Keys in Hashicorp Vault.

Answer (score 1):

Some support for utilizing OTP during CLI scripting was added in recent Keycloak releases. I've not played with it so far, so i can't present you any recipes. Try to start at Authentication -> HTTP challenge Flow settings.

Regarding to users token you can implement required functionality as an SPI extension to Keycloak (see Server Development section in docs). From my point of view there should be two components:

1. User token issuer
2. Custom authenticator that will be used in authentication flow for your client

Here is rough example:

1. Let User tokens be like UUID strings, so all user tokens could be stored in user attributes (Attributes tab in user's settings Admin UI).
2. Some of your APIs could introduce dedicated endpoint that will accept valid Access Token< generate new UUID User Token, store it in keycloak user attributes via Admin API and return this token to user.
3. Then we create custom Authenticator SPI implementation that will extract user token from direct grant auth request and validate it.
4. And last step is to properly configure direct grant authentication flow for corresponding OIDC client. This flow should work like default if no user token presented in auth request and should validate only user token and ignore other credentials if user token presents.

Keycloak "server development" docs and keycloak sources are very helpful with such king of tasks.